# cache size in SPDK memory pool create

Tags: c, caching, dpdk

I'm reading the code of SPDK. There is an argument of *spdk_mempool_create* called cache_size. *spdk_mempool_create* will call *spdk_mempool_create_ctor* and eventually call function from dpdk. I know that dpdk will create cache for each core. But I couldn't understand this sentence in *spdk_mempool_create_ctor*

```
    /* No more than half of all elements can be in cache */
    tmp = (count / 2) / rte_lcore_count();
    if (cache_size > tmp) {
        cache_size = tmp;
    }
```

I don't understand why we should not put more than half of all elements in the cache?
Can someone explain? Thanks.